# AWS Step Functions Graph Export API

Tags: amazon-web-services

With regards to the AWS Step Functions graph, is there a way to export/download it programmatically?

I want to automate the downloading of the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this feedback incase someone else runs into a similar issue. I decided to extract the Step Functions graph related code from the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code and create a small react library to embed in a web page.

Here is the link to my library [@tshepomgaga/aws-sfn-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tshepomgaga/aws-sfn-graph).

With this library in-hand, I can set up a small web app to load the AWS States Language JSON from a server and render the graph on a page.

Using a library like [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) I can run a headless automation to download the graph image from the web app.

That is my solution in a nutshell but I would have preferred to call an API from AWS to download the image.

Comment: Can I also use this to show what happened in the execution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudiocode/) and the state machine will render right in your IDE.

[State machine graph visualization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/bulding-stepfunctions.html#bulding-stepfunctions-visualizations)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding but I was looking for a programmatic (API) solution for downloading the image.

Comment: @TshepoMgaga seems like there no API call to specifically download the graph image. You can take a look at the available api calls available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/Welcome.html). The good part of `toolkit` is that it will render any state machine which you have deployed or going to deploy.