# Is it possible to export AWS Step Functions Graph Export with what happened in the execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

From [AWS Step Functions Graph Export API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65968624/aws-step-functions-graph-export-api), I am able to export the graph workflow only. Is it possible to show the states of each node? (Succeeded,Failed..etc)

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the executions with [ListExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ListExecutions.html) to get the execution ARNs. Then call [GetExecutionHistory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html) to get the event details for each execution.

Typescript example:

```js
const res = await client.send( new ListExecutionsCommand({ stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-xxxx-x-xxxxxxxxxxx',}));

const executions = res.executions ?? [];

const detailsRes = await Promise.all(
  executions.map((e) => client.send(new GetExecutionHistoryCommand({ executionArn: e.executionArn,})));
);
```

Event detail example from the history output:

```js
{
  "id": 11,
  "previousEventId": 9,
  "stateExitedEventDetails": {
    "name": "AllJobs",
    "output": "[...]",
    "outputDetails": { "truncated": false }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-01-06T19:41:37.035Z",
  "type": "ParallelStateExited"
},
```

Each list-execution output has a `status` property. The event history output includes a list of event details. The last
event will have `"type": "ExecutionSucceeded"` if the execution succeeded and `"type": "ExecutionFailed"` if the execution failed.

Comment: Yes, seems like I will have to use custom code to combine GetExecutionHistory and the react library shared

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible from **ListExecutions** request. You can add filter of **statusFilter** and get the executions. Calling this API with required filters will get you the states you're looking for.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ExecutionListItem.html#StepFunctions-Type-ExecutionListItem-status

Comment: I need to see the status of each step within the execution

Comment: There's no documented ready made solution to what you're looking for. You have to do some custom development using the method I shared in answer.